# Why am I overselling products?

Tags: magento-1.8, sales-order

I am running a Magento CE 1.8.1.0 - This question is about Magento, and no third party modules.

All the products on my site are configurables. At times I would oversell some products. Investigating these orders led me to the quote object.

For all of the orders which I have oversold I can see a quote, but I see no quote items in the sales_flat_quote_items table. Why is this so?

Also looking at the sales_flat_order_items table, I see, for these orders no simple entries, only configurables.

I wrote a simple sql to lookup quotes that have no quote items, and there seem to be a lot. Why is this so?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT increment_id) FROM db.sales_flat_order sfo 
LEFT JOIN db.sales_flat_quote_item sfqi
ON sfo.quote_id = sfqi.quote_id
WHERE sfqi.quote_id IS NULL;
```

UPDATE:
I have manage to reproduce the issue to a degree.

STEPS TO REPRODUCE. 
Add a config product to the cart, check the sales_flat_quote_items table, see 2 rows (config+simple) - delete the simple row leaving only the config. Order get's placed successfull no stock is deducted from the simple

I think this is what is happening to me - will investigate further but I think this could happen in stock magento stores with high volume traffic because there doesn't seem to be a check on this

For the record, my site regularly sees con-currents of 3000+

Comment: So you are selling products that have no stock in Magento at the time of placing the order? Are you using any 3th party modules in the shop?

Comment: Yes. Magento is set to deduct stock at checkout, but I am selling more stock than what I have. I have installed a stock movements module, https://www.bubbleshop.net/magento-stock-movements.html and it shows stock movement on the config product, which is what I am thinking why I am overselling. It is this investigation that lead me further down the magento rabit hole :) and that lead me to ask my question

Comment: Did you reach out to Bubble code / Johan Reinke with this issue? He knows the code of the module and can help you with the issue

Comment: I feel like we are going down the wrong track here. Did you read the question? I used the stock movement module to help me track down the bug, which is what I explained very clearly in my original question.

Comment: Ahh ok, my mistake. I thought it caused the issue. It wasn't too clear.

Comment: @Marius Can you please un-hold this question? I have rephrased it and given steps to reproduce. I believe the question is not off topic as you marked it.

Answer (score 1):

Like you spelled it out, you manually delete a record from the database.
Because there is no relation with the sold simple product, it will not update the stock.

I've took a look at the code, you've `ajaxDeleteAction` for the minicart and `deleteAction` for the cart to remove items, it is given a `quote_item_id`.

`$quote->removeItem($itemId)`

```
/**
 * Remove quote item by item identifier
 *
 * @param   int $itemId
 * @return  Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
 */
public function removeItem($itemId)
{
    $item = $this->getItemById($itemId);

    if ($item) {
        $item->setQuote($this);
        /**
         * If we remove item from quote - we can't use multishipping mode
         */
        $this->setIsMultiShipping(false);
        $item->isDeleted(true);
        if ($item->getHasChildren()) {
            foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                $child->isDeleted(true);
            }
        }

        $parent = $item->getParentItem();
        if ($parent) {
            $parent->isDeleted(true);
        }

        Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_quote_remove_item', array('quote_item' => $item));
    }

    return $this;
}
```

It looks at both, if it has a parent or if it has children.

Bottom line, still think some custom code is messing up things.

Answer (score 0):

We managed to reproduce, and fix this issue. It's detailed in a PR to openmage here: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/issues/364